# 1024 bit to 2048 bit certificate differences in how we access our portal

Tags: web-hosting, security, https

Why now that we have gone from 1024 to 2048 do we need to put the www in front of our portal site when we never used to.

Comment: Are you sure that the certificate was not registered to "www.yourdomain.ext" whereas it was to "yourdomain.ext" before

Answer (score 2):

The bit encryption level does not impact the domain name used.  Most likely the certificate was ordered with just domain.com instead of www.domain.com.

Depending on your vendor, you may be able to get a re-issue if this was done recently.

Also, some vendors will include both domain.com and www.domain.com if you order www.domain.com.

Comment: I always thought it was the other way around: that usually the certificate is given to the second level domain: `example.com`, but traditionally some CAs also provide the `www.` subdomain as an alias for free. `www` being a special case due to many sites using the `www` and no `www` domain names interchangeably for the website. Issuing the certificate to the second-level domain makes sense as the certificate could be used for more than just HTTPS, including for SFTP/SSH and other services which wouldn't make sense to use the `www` prefix.

Comment: This depends on the vendor.  Most clients (HTTP/SSH/Email) will throw and error if the domain used to connect is not in the certs list.  RapidSSL for example will give you the domain.com if you order www.domain.com but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Jeff, there is no relation between sub-domain and level of encryption. The certificate is being issued to particular domain (www.domain.ext or domain.ext) that is depend of certificate buyer who specified the domain at the time of purchase.

There are different type of certificates are being issued by CA that can work on with www and without www version of your domain.